# AWS Aurora database read replica autoscaling - best practices for django project to connect your application to newly created databases?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, master-slave, amazon-aurora

Using AWS Aurora database service - you can configure master-slave replication and slave autoscaling (e.g. if slave CPU is higher than 75 percent - create a second slave).

Newly created database has a new endpoint (host) which is not registered by django yet.

What would be the best approach to firstly discover the newly created database and add it to a running django application?

I am thinking about pinging every X seconds using, lets say, aws cli and checking how many slaves are there. But the problem with this is if a slave is destroyed by an autoscaling group - my django application would start erroring, so an appropriate handling is also required...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be configuring each read replica's endpoint with django. You should configure it to use the [reader endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Endpoints.html) provided by Aurora, which will load-balance the requests across all read replicas in the cluster. Then when a new read replica is added to the cluster django will automatically be using it.